# Return number of rows in a section in table view from an array in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview

I'm creating a table view that will track meals. For context, I have two other swift files each with a struct Meal and the other is a Food struct (as shown in code below in the "meals" variable initialized.

```
var meals: [Meal] = [Meal(name: "breakfast", food: [Food(name: "eggs", description: "3 eggs")]), Meal(name: "lunch", food: [Food(name: "sandwich", description: "ham and cheese sandwich")]), Meal(name: "dinner", food: [Food(name: "steak", description: "steak with a side of potatoes")])]
```

What I'm being asked is how to return the number of rows in each section (each section being a meal object).

I got the numberofSections to return the number of sections by typing meals.count to return the value of objects:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return meals.count
}
```

Now I need to access the amount of "Food" objects in each the meal objects in the numberOfRows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return meals.food.count
}
```

But I get an error that says "Value of type [Meal] has no member "food". I don't know what else to do. In this case I only put one food object in each meal object, so I know the value will be 1, but I need to access the number from the variable directly.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the count of the `food` array for the individual `Meal` that corresponds to the section in that method.  So the simple solution is like so:

```
return meals[section].food.count
```